# Testing and integrating plain ruby objects into a Rails 3.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After watching the [Fasts Rails Tests](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/641-gogaruco2011-fast-rails-tests) talk by Corey and reading through [Object on Rails](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/11/15/early-access-beta-of-objects-on-rails-now-available-2/) by Avdi I am in the process of setting up my new Rails 3.2 application to take advantage of these concepts.

In order to get everything working I started with this example spec file.

```
# spec_no_rails/projects/financials_spec.rb
require_relative '../spec_no_rails_helper'

class DummyProject
  include Modules::Projects::Financials
end

describe Modules::Projects::Financials do
  it 'should have some method' do
    DummyProject.new.foo.should == 'bar'
  end
end
```

And this was the intialial spec_no_rails_helper.rb file that is used to require the modules

```
# spec_no_rails/spec_no_rails_helper.rb
Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/app/pimms/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

I then set about creating the new example module.

```
# app/pimms/modules/projects/financials.rb
module Modules::Projects::Financials
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end
```

In order to see that everything was going to work when I included the new stand alone module into one of my ActiveRecord classes I added the following line into one of my models.

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Modules::Projects::Financials
end
```

This allowed me to open up console and see that everything is working as expected.

```
> Project.first.foo
=> "bar"
```

So at this stage I have defined a namespaced stand alone module defined under app/pimms/modules/projects/financials.rb which I can included into a Rails model and everything works as expected.

The problem I'm having is when I try to run the specs I get the following.

```
> bundle exec rspec spec_no_rails/
/Users/scott/Code/pimms/spec_no_rails/projects/financials_spec.rb:5:in `<class:DummyProject>': uninitialized constant DummyProject::Modules (NameError)
  from /Users/scott/Code/pimms/spec_no_rails/projects/financials_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
  from /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

So the reason this happens is because the Modules::Projects namespaces has not been defined when the tests are being run. I'm guesing I didn't have to define the Modules::Projects namespace when I used the module with the Rails application because Rails handled that for me.

In order to get the test to run as expected I had to define the namespace in the spec_no_rails_helper.rb file like this.

```
# spec_no_rails/spec_no_rails_helper.rb
module Modules
  module Projects
  end
end

Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/app/pimms/**/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
```

This obviously isn't ideal as I would have to manually create all the namespaces for any stand alone modules or classes that I wasnt to test outside of Rails.

Is there a better way to setup my Rails application so that I can easily run a test suite without relying on Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because of how you've defined the module. You're attempting to define it like this:

```
module Modules::Projects::Financials
  def foo
   'bar'
  end
end
```

But Ruby will interpret this by attempting to find the `Modules` module first, then the `Projects` module and then will finally define the `Financials` module, but ONLY if it can find the first two.

In your case, it *can't* find the first two and so bombs out like that.

Go ahead, fire up `irb` and copy and paste the above code example into it. You'll see exactly the same error that you're getting when you run your specs.

---

The way to fix this is to just define/re-open the module in each file:

```
module Modules
  module Projects
    module Financials
      def foo
        'bar'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now that each time each one of these files is loaded, it will either define or re-open the modules, adding functionality to them. The best part about this is that it doesn't matter if `Modules` is or isn't defined first, it'll just define it anyway.

---

Now to address the point: Why does it work in Rails?

**Oh man, Rails is totally doing some awesome stuff!**

I actually covered how Rails deals with the automatic definition of modules [in my "wrong argument type" screencast](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/11/screencast-wrong-argument-type/). Well, I don't exactly cover how modules are automatically loaded, but (*spoiler alert*) it's the culprit for what's going wrong there.

I'm not going to force you to watch it. The problem lies with [these lines inside `activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L488-492).

The `load_missing_constant` method is used by Rails when it can't find a constant. That's when Rails's magic autoloading stuff kicks into gear. It calls this method, and attempts to find a file that defines this module.

If it can't do that, it does this:

```
mod = Module.new
into.const_set const_name, mod
autoloaded_constants << qualified_name unless autoload_once_paths.include?(base_path)
return mod
```

This is [inside the `autoload_module!` method in that `dependencies.rb` file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L433-439).

What this code does is simple: creates a new module, sets its constant name to the one that's missing, adds the `qualified_name` to the `autoloaded_constants` and returns that module.

This is why Rails is defining your modules *even though they don't really exist*. You're completely bypassing this in your spec (with good reason, you don't want all of that nasty Rails junk), and so it's not automatically loading the modules.

Comment: So why does the first syntax work when run within Rails? Is Rails automatically defining modules that it can't find?

Comment: Updated! Read below the line for an explanation.